# How to inject application config into app module in angular

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection, angular-config

I am using Angular v16 and I have the following config that needs to be included in **app.module**. What is the best way to inject appConfig in **app.module**? It works if I include them directly inside **app.module** providers, but I want to manage all the dependencies in a separate config file.

Note: I'm not using standalone component for app.component.ts. So I can't use `bootstrapApplication` to to inject them

**app.config.ts**

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
   providers: [
     provideAnimations(),
     provideHttpClient(),
     provideRouter(
        appRoutes,
        withInMemoryScrolling({scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}),
     ),
   ]
}
```

**main.ts**

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I got a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I remember having trouble with config not getting loaded in time, and solving it using a service and HttpBackend (it "dispatches requests directly to the backend, without going through the interceptor chain.")

**ConfigService**

```
export class ConfigService {

  private appConfig: Config

  // Using handler: HttpBackend in constructor, this way synced config init can use httpClient
  private httpBackEnd: HttpClient

  constructor(
    public handler: HttpBackend
  ) {
    this.httpBackEnd = new HttpClient(handler)
  }


  loadConfig() {
    return this.httpBackEnd.get<Config>('config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        (config: Config) => { this.appConfig = config },
        (err) => { console.log('Failed to load config.json. ' + err) }
      )
  }

  get params() {
    if (!this.appConfig) { throw Error('Trying to use config, but it was not yet loaded!') }
    return this.appConfig
  }
}
```

And then, in app.module, calling loadConfig in a provider:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return () => {
          return config.loadConfig()
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

**Example of config.json**

```
{
  "api": {
    "domain": "http://homestead.test/",
    "route": "/v4"
  },
  "logoutRedirectPath": "/user/login",
  "devMode": false
}
```

The properties defined inside config.json are then available everywhere I import ConfigService and accessing e.g. `this.configService.params.api.domain`.

The other advantage is, the config can be updated, and the app does not need to be recompiled to take effect.

Comment: I load my configs from a web API service but had the same issue with it being too late for my Angular components due to the async nature of the web calls. Loading the configs from the web API only once for the app also makes sense. Your approach with the APP_INITIALIZER solved it for me as well. Nice post!

Comment: Hey, awesome to hear it helped! =D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right - this is the suitable place to use `forRoot()` static method concept, see this example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from './app-config.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [AppConfigService],
})
export class AppModule{
  static forRoot(config: AppConfig): ModuleWithProviders<AppModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: AppModule,
      providers: [{ provide: AppConfig, useValue: config }],
    };
  }
}
```

in this way, you can inject from the outside the configuration you need and it will be loaded into the module.
to implement it, you simply do this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
.bootstrapModule(AppModule.forRoot(YOUR CONFIGURATION OBJECT))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score -1):

You should just import your constant into `app.module.ts`.

```
import { appConfig } from './app.config';
```

And then use it like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app.config';

@NgModule({
  ...appConfig
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you want to define all the app metadata into your constant (imports, providers, exports, etc...) Make sure your `AppConfig` interface matches the one required info NgModule decorator one (more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules#ngmodule-metadata).)

Comment: its not working. I tried that before. It's only working in following way but I have to optimize it for non-standalone `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: This is just pasting the config object directly into app.module. It wont work and is same as writing config URL into app.module itself.